# How to uninstall java from mac completely? JRE and JDK

Tags: java, macos

I did navigate to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and removed the jdk, and there is nothing in that folder anymore. But my terminal shows I have some version of java, so I am a little confused, I wanna uninstall java completely from my laptop. I did uninstall JRE too using a set of commands.

steps to reproduce

1. `java -version`

   output:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: How did you solve this problem ?

Comment: tip: `find / -name java` might help you find it, sometimes it's under /usr etc.

Comment: `which java` is also helpful

Comment: @JohnGilmer `which java` may be useful in some cases, but e.g. on my system it returns `/usr/bin/java`, which is macOS's shim that runs the actual java located in `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java`. Still, good advice :)

Answer (score 14):

To uninstall AdoptOpenJDK installed via Homebrew,

```
brew uninstall adoptopenjdk8
```

To uninstall OpenJDK installed via Homebrew,

```
brew uninstall openjdk8
```

Answer (score 2):

The `/usr/bin/java` and other related tools are macOS shims that run a specific version of Java, as defined by the `JAVA_HOME` variable.

This variable is usually set in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)`
```

You can check the current value:

```bash
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@8/1.8.0-392/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You may have multiple versions of Java installed, to list them all:

```bash
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    21.0.1 (x86_64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 21.0.1" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
    17.0.9 (x86_64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 17.0.9" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.9/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_392 (x86_64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 8" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@8/1.8.0-392/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

In my case, you can see there are three versions of OpenJDK installed via homebrew. I can look them up in the list of installed packages:

```bash
$ brew list | grep -iE 'java|jdk|temurin'
openjdk
openjdk@17
openjdk@8
```

If I wanted to remove all of them, I could do `brew uninstall` them one by one, or:

```bash
$ for pkg in $(brew list | grep -iE 'java|jdk|temurin'); do brew uninstall $pkg; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew untap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
```

Comment: Can you explain what those commands do and how this differs from the existing approaches?

Answer (score -1):

1. Click on the Finder icon located in your dock
2. Click on Go in the Finder menu
3. Click on Utilities
4. Double-click on the Terminal icon
5. In the Terminal window Copy and Paste the commands below:

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```

Reference : https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml

Comment: You may have multiple versions of jdk installed. Can you please check by using `ls` that the jdk `1.8.0_152-release` is not there in folder `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.